# SwiftUI: How do you restart a timer after cancelling it?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a navigation view consisting of the main **ContentView** and a **TimerView**. The TimerView has a timer which correctly increments and also correctly stops when I call `self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()`.

However when I go back to ContentView and then navigate to TimerView again, I want the timer to start counting again however this does not happen. `secondsElapsed` does reset to 0 but the timer doesn't run.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: TimerView()) {
                Text("Go to Timer View")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TimerView: View {
    @State var secondsElapsed = 0
    var timer = Timer.publish (every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(self.secondsElapsed) seconds elapsed")
            Button("Stop timer",
                   action: {
                    self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
            })
        }.onReceive(timer) { _ in
            self.secondsElapsed += 1
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31):

To my knowledge (and historically), Timer cannot be restarted after cancellation or invalidation.

What I do is just re-declare the timer.

## Update 12/2021:

The previous code was from SwiftUI 1, which had some "oddities," especially around lifecycle.  So, I updated the code to how I would do it in SwiftUI 3.

For this code, you must `import combine` to declare a `Cancellable` type.

Here is an example with some added personal preferences:

```
struct TimerView: View {
    @State var secondsElapsed = 0
    @State var timer: Timer.TimerPublisher = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
    @State var connectedTimer: Cancellable? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(self.secondsElapsed) seconds elapsed")
            Button("Stop Timer", action: {
                self.cancelTimer()
            })
            Button("Continue Timer", action: {
                self.instantiateTimer()
            })
            Button("Restart Timer", action: {
                self.restartTimer()
            })
        }.onAppear {
            self.instantiateTimer()
        }.onDisappear {
            self.cancelTimer()
        }.onReceive(timer) { _ in
            self.secondsElapsed += 1
        }
    }
    
    func instantiateTimer() {
        self.timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
        self.connectedTimer = self.timer.connect()
        return
    }
    
    func cancelTimer() {
        self.connectedTimer?.cancel()
        return
    }
    
    func resetCounter() {
        self.secondsElapsed = 0
        return
    }
    
    func restartTimer() {
        self.secondsElapsed = 0
        self.cancelTimer()
        self.instantiateTimer()
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.timer.connect()` gives a warning of `Result of call to 'connect()' is unused`

Comment: @Patrick It's been a while since I answered this question, but I think there was weirdness around the timer lifecycle and instantiating `Timer` (e.g. .connect() behaved differently in SwiftUI 1).  Try the updated answer and let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Having a variable inside a `View` which isn't attached to a `@State` variable or an `@ObservedObject` model doesn't seem to have very well defined documentation - but the general rule is that everything without a `@State/@ObservedObject` annotation is essentially throwaway - especially as `TimerView` is a `struct` and won't be preserved over re-renders.

`Timer.TimerPublisher` is a class - so essentially this would boil down to either two use cases

- If its transient (ie: resets when the view is removed from screen and reloaded) then put the timer in a `@State` (be aware of strong retention with `self` captures - again documentation is thin on how `onReceive` stores its connections)
- If its non-transient (ie: preserved over the view loading/unloading) then it needs to go into an external model (or a global `var`) and brought in via the `init` call for `TimerView`

That you have `@State var secondsElapsed` makes me think it should be transient

Answer (score 2):

if you have a countdown timer, you define it something like this:

```
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

...and use it on a Text field for e.g.:

```
    Text("Punkte: \(Punkte.formatnumber())")
        .onReceive(timer) { input in
                            if time < 1 { gameOver() } else { self.time -= TimerToggle ? 1 : 0  }
                    }
```

so you only have to set the Toggle in the action of the button:

```
Button(action: { TimerToggle.toggle() }, label: {
                    Text("Pause")
                })
```

Much simpler and works in **SwiftUI 5.2**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to manage the state of the timer, my ugly but effective solution was to not actually stop the timer. In the timer's message handler, you can just not increment the secondsElapsed if its value is < 0.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: TimerView()) {
                Text("Go to Timer View")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TimerView: View {
    @State var secondsElapsed = 0 // if < 0 then timer is stopped
    var timer = Timer.publish (every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if self.secondsElapsed > 0 {
                Text("\(self.secondsElapsed) seconds elapsed")
            }
            else {
                Text("Timer stopped")
            }
            Button("Stop timer",
                   action: stopTimer)
        }.onReceive(timer) { _ in
            if secondsElapsed >= 0 {
                self.secondsElapsed += 1
            }
        }
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        self.secondsElapsed = -1
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the publisher may lead to state reset, which can be undesired (eg cancelling an animation)

here is another take, using an ObservableObject object

```
class TimerUpdater: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @InvalidatingTimer var timer: Timer?
    
    @Published var tick: Int = 0
    
    var repeating: TimeInterval = 1
    
    init(repeating: TimeInterval) {
     
        super.init()
        
        self.repeating = repeating
        
        continueTimer()
        
    }
    
    func stopTimer() {
        timer = nil
    }

    func continueTimer() {
        timer = nil
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: repeating, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] timer in
            self?.tick += 1
        })
    }

}

struct SampleViewThatNeedToBeTimerUpdated: View {
    
    @StateObject var timerUpdater = TimerUpdater(repeating: 5)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        SomeView()
        .onDraggingBegan({
            timerUpdater.stopTimer()
        })
        .onDraggingEnded({
            timerUpdater.continueTimer()
        })
        .onChange(of: timerUpdater.tick, perform: { _ in
            
            withAnimation {
                ...
            }
            
        })
        .onDisappear {
            timerUpdater.stopTimer()
        }
                  
    }
    
}
```