# Observe singleton timer value changes with Publisher in Combine

Tags: swift, timer, swiftui, combine

One of the requirements of my application is the ability to start multiple timers, for reporting purposes.

I've tried to store the timers and seconds passed in an `@EnvironmentObject` with `@Published` variables, but every time the object refreshes, any view that observes the `@EnvironmentObject` refreshes too.

Example

```swift
class TimerManager: ObservableObject {
   @Published var secondsPassed: [String: Int]
   var timers: [String:AnyCancellable]

   func startTimer(itemId: String) {
      self.secondsPassed[itemId] = 0
      self.timers[itemId] = Timer
          .publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
          .autoconnect()
          .sink(receiveValue: { _ in
                self.secondsPassed[itemId]! += 1
          })
   }

   func isTimerValid(itemId: String) -> Bool {
       return self.timers[itemId].isTimerValid
   }

   // other code...
}
```

So for example, if in any other view I need to know if a particular timer is active by calling a function `isTimerValid`, I need to include this `@EnvironmentObject` in that view, and it won't stop refreshing it because the timer changes `secondsPassed` which is `Published`, causing lags and useless redrawings.

So one thing I did was to cache the `itemId` of the active timers somewhere else, in a `static` `struct` that I update every time I start or stop a timer.

It seemed a bit hacky, so lately I've been thinking to move all this into a Singleton, like this for example

```swift
class SingletonTimerManager {

   static let singletonTimerManager = SingletonTimerManager()

   var secondsPassed: [String: Int]
   var timers: [String:AnyCancellable]

   func startTimer(itemId: String) {
      self.secondsPassed[itemId] = 0
      self.timers[itemId] = Timer
          .publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
          .autoconnect()
          .sink(receiveValue: { _ in
                self.secondsPassed[itemId]! += 1
          })
   }

   // other code...
}
```

and **only let some Views** observe the changes to `secondsPassed`. On the plus side, I can maybe move the timer on the background thread.

I've been struggling how to do this properly.

These are my `Views` (albeit a very simple extract)

```
struct ContentView: View {

    // set outside the ContentView
    var selectedItemId: String

    // timerValue: set by a publisher?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {  
            ItemView(seconds: Binding.constant(timerValue))
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    @Binding var seconds: Int

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(self.seconds)")
    }
}
```

I need to somehow observe the `SingletonChronoManager.secondsPassed[selectedItemId]` so the `ItemView` updates in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using the following solution, combining @heckj suggestion and [this one from @Mykel.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60924778/4663815)

What I did was separating the `AnyCancellable` from the `TimerPublishers` by saving them in specific dictionaries of `SingletonTimerManager`.

Then, every time an `ItemView` is declared, I instantiate an autoconnected `@State TimerPublisher`. Every Timer instance now runs in the `.common` `RunLoop`, with a `0.5` tolerance to better help the perfomance as suggested by Paul here: [Triggering events repeatedly using a timer](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/triggering-events-repeatedly-using-a-timer)

During the `.onAppear()` call of the `ItemView`, if a publisher  with the same `itemId` already exists in `SingletonTimerManager`, I just assign that publisher to the one of my view.

Then I handle it like in @Mykel solution, with start and stopping both ItemView's publisher and SingletonTimerManager publisher.

The `secondsPassed` are shown in a text stored inside `@State var seconds`, which gets updated with a `onReceive()` attached to the `ItemView`'s publisher.

I know that I'm probably creating too many publishers with this solution and I can't pinpoint exactly what happens when copying a publisher variable into another, but overall perfomance is much better now.

**Sample Code:**

**SingletonTimerManager**

```
class SingletonTimerManager {
   static let singletonTimerManager = SingletonTimerManager()

   var secondsPassed: [String: Int]
   var cancellables: [String:AnyCancellable]
   var publishers: [String: TimerPublisher]

   func startTimer(itemId: String) {
      self.secondsPassed[itemId] = 0
      self.publisher[itemId] = Timer
          .publish(every: 1, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common)
      self.cancellables[itemId] = self.publisher[itemId]!.autoconnect().sink(receiveValue: {_ in self.secondsPassed[itemId] += 1})
   }

   func isTimerValid(_ itemId: String) -> Bool {
       if(self.cancellables[itemId] != nil && self.publishers[itemId] != nil) {
           return true
       }
       return false
   }
}
```

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var itemIds: [String]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {  
            ForEach(self.itemIds, id: \.self) { itemId in
                ItemView(itemId: itemId)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    var itemId: String
    @State var seconds: Int
    @State var timerPublisher = Timer.publish(every: 1, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        Button("StartTimer") {
            // Call startTimer in SingletonTimerManager....
            self.timerPublisher = SingletonTimerManager.publishers[itemId]! 
            self.timerPublisher.connect()
        }
        Button("StopTimer") {
            self.timerPublisher.connect().cancel()
            // Call stopTimer in SingletonTimerManager....
        }
        Text("\(self.seconds)")
            .onAppear {
                // function that checks if the timer with this itemId is running
                if(SingletonTimerManager.isTimerValid(itemId)) {
                     self.timerPublisher = SingletonTimerManager.publishers[itemId]!
                     self.timerPublisher.connect()
                }
            }.onReceive($timerPublisher) { _ in
                self.seconds = SingletonTimerManager.secondsPassed[itemId] ?? 0
            }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By putting the timer publisher results into Environment, you are propagating change notifications to all views within the tree that define that environment object, which I'm sure will cause un-needed redraws and performance issues (and as you've seen).

A better mechanism is strongly limiting the views (or subviews) that need to display the constantly updating time, and pass in a reference to a timer publisher directly to them rather than layering it into the environment. Putting the timer itself into a singleton is one option but not critical to this, and won't effect the cascading redraws you're seeing.

[How to use a timer with SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-a-timer-with-swiftui) has a "shoving a timer into the view itself", which may work for what you're trying to do, but slightly better is the video here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/triggering-events-repeatedly-using-a-timer

In Paul's example, he's stuffing the timer into the view itself - wouldn't be my choice, but for a simple real-time clock view it's not bad. You could just as easily pass in the timer publisher from an external object - like your singleton for example.