# Start and stop Timer based on boolean

Tags: swift, swiftui, timer, boolean

How can I cancel and start a `Timer` based on a Boolean that is a computed variable in swift?

Here is a stripped down version of my current code. The Timer gets cancelled but I haven't figured out how to re-declare it.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var fetcher: TestFetcher
    
    var item: Item
    var isActive: Bool {
        fetcher.currentItemId == item.id
    }
    
    @State private var counter = 0
    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(seconds)")
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    if (isActive) {
                        seconds += 1
                    } else {
                        timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}
```

So far I tried to create the `Timer` as a computed variable too:

```
var timer: Any? {
    if (fetcher.currentItemId == item.id) {
        return Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    } else {
        return timer.connect().cancel()
    }
}

[Error]: Instance method 'onReceive(_:perform:)' requires that 'Any?' conform to 'Publisher'
```

Or mutate the `self.timer` within the `isActive` property

```
var isActive: Bool {
    let _bool = fetcher.currentItemId == item.id
    
    if (_bool) {
        self.timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    } else {
        self.timer.connect().cancel()
    }
    
    return _bool
}

(Won't work because computed properties don't update itself nor didSet is available)
```

Comment: This looks to be SwiftUI. You should add that tag.

Comment: could you explain what you mean by `...how to revoke it`. Do you want to re-start it?
If so, then have a look at this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59241293/swiftui-how-do-you-restart-a-timer-after-cancelling-it

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine yes, I mean to re-declare the variable (or re-start in your words). Thanks for the hint, using the lifecycle events fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Based on @workingdogsupportUkraine hint I've got it working by using lifecycle events – whether the workaround is not the answer to the initial question

> "How can I cancel and start a Timer based on a Boolean that is a
> computed variable in swift?"

But in this specific scenario, this will also work:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var fetcher: TestFetcher
    
    var item: Item
    
    @State private var counter = 0
    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
    @State private var connectedTimer = Cancellable? = nil

    private func cancelTimer() {
        self.connectedTimer?.cancel()
    }
    
    private func resetTimer() {
        self.timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
        self.connectedTimer = self.timer.connect()
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(seconds)")
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    seconds += 1
                })
        }
        .onAppear() {
            if (fetcher.currentItemId == item.id) {
                resetTimer()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: fetcher.currentItemId, perform: { newValue in
            if (newValue == item.id) {
                resetTimer()
            } else {
                cancelTimer()
            }
        })
    }
}
```